# How create dependent generic protocol in swift

Tags: ios, generics, swift, enums

I'm trying to using protocols to give certain specifications to structs that will implement them, but I need to be able to make these generic.

For example:

```
protocol NodeType {
}

protocol EdgeType {
  var fromNode: NodeType
  var toNode: NodeType
}
```

The problem is that both node could be different structs type that implement that implement the protocol NodeType

In a perfect world I would need this:

```
protocol EdgeType<T: NodeType> {
  var fromNode: T
  var toNode: T
}
```

to make sure that both nodes are the same class or struct type

Is something like this possible currently in swift?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [how to create generic protocols in swift iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469913/how-to-create-generic-protocols-in-swift-ios), [Swift Generic Protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082769/swift-generic-protocol).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at **[Associated Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_289)**. They're kind of generics for protocols.

```
protocol NodeType {

}

protocol EdgeType {

    associatedtype Node: NodeType

    var fromNode: Node { get }
    var toNode: Node { get }

}
```

Then you can conform to `EdgeType` by specifying the concrete `NodeType` implementation:

```
struct MyNode: NodeType {

}

struct MyEdge: EdgeType {

    associatedtype Node = MyNode

    var fromNode: MyNode {
        return MyNode()
    }

    var toNode: MyNode {
        return MyNode()
    }

}
```